# Как записать значения из строки в отдельные переменные?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть Dataframe, в котором мне необходимо брать значения за последнюю дату и значения внутри строки записывать в разные переменные.

Первую часть задачи решаю и получаю строку показанную ниже.

Как мне записать в отдельные переменные значения из получаемой строки:

```
DATA                           RUR     USD     EUR
2020-07-09 00:54:49.705148  3,4301  2,4399  2,7547
```

```
Т.е
Y= 3,4301 (значение в RUR)
Z= 2,4399 (значение в USD) 
X= 2,754 (значение в EUR)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# если столбец `DATA` уже имеет тип данных `datetime64`, то эту строку можно не выполнять
df["DATA"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATA"], errors="coerce")


rur, usd, eur = df.loc[df["DATA"].idxmax(), ["RUR", "USD", "EUR"]].to_list()
```

---

результат:

```
In [19]: rur
Out[19]: '3,4301'

In [20]: usd
Out[20]: '2,4399'

In [21]: rur
Out[21]: '3,4301'
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for *_, Y, Z, X in df.iloc:
    # some action with Y, Z, X
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Признаться, не очень понял ваш ответ